# Check if Action input parameter is null

Tags: c#

I have a method with the signature below.  I put in checks to make sure that the inputs are not null.  However, with input parameters that are an Action it is always seeing the input as null.  What is a better way to perform this check for inputs that are of Action Type?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
public void DeleteTreeValue(TreeValue treeValue, Action<Exception> callback)
{
    if (treeValue == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("treeValue");

    //This is always throwing the ArugmentNullException even when the callback is passed
    if (callback == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
```

EDIT: Here is an example of how it is being called. I can see the method in the call back when I debug it, but this could still be seen as null in the arg check which is probably what is happening.

```
[Test]
public void DeleteValueShouldThowExceptionWhenValueDoesNotExist()
{
    var myValue = new TreeValue {TreeValueId = -1};
    _dataService.DeleteTreeValue(myValue, exception =>
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(exception);

    });
}
```

Comment: How are you calling this? The `callback` can't be `null` if you don't pass `null`.

Comment: Is there a problem with _dataService being null?

Comment: `Assert.IsNotNull` returns `void`. Maybe that's why?

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the problem, like removing treeValue parameter temporarily, moving both pieces of code to single project, or running them in another machine. It's not easy to repro it in my machine.